# What is Powered Output?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

I'm using the MC Forestry mod, which has machines that have powered output.

I've tried taking items out of the machines by using the regular wood pipe to stone pipe, which doesn't work. What exactly does powered output mean, and how can I get items out of these machines using pipes?

Answer (score 2):

Forestry machines automatically eject items to buildcraft compatible pipes and chests  standing next to them. If a chest and a pipe are connected to a machine, it will output to pipe only.

Use diamond pipes to sort those saplings/seeds/etc. to a planter (arboretum, farm, etc.) and useful product automatically.

Comment: Most blocks have sided-output. For example the logger ejects logs from the sides and sapling and apples from the top and bottom.

Comment: @RonanForman: true, forgot about this detail. On the other hand, a Combine doesn't sort its output so you have to do it yourself.